# CSS select last of type and not sub-types

Tags: html, css

I have an element with children and some of those children themselves have children, some of which use a shared CSS class.

What I'm wanting to do is select the last child of the main element and not also the last sub-child.

I have tried in 2 ways I know thus far:

**last-child**

```css
.some-class:last-child {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="some-class">one</div>
  <div>
      <div class="some-class">sub-one</div>
      <div class="some-class">sub-two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="some-class">two</div>
</div>
```

**Last-of-type**

```css
.some-class:last-of-type {
      background: lightblue;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="some-class">one</div>
      <div>
          <div class="some-class">sub-one</div>
          <div class="some-class">sub-two</div>
      </div>
      <div class="some-class">two</div>
    </div>
```

You will see that both of these have `two` and `sub-two` to be highlighted in blue... I simply **only** want `two` to be highlighted.

Comment: Be aware with these answers that the element MUST be the actual `last-child`. You cannot select `last-of -class`.

Answer (score 2):

You can target the last element of `.some-class` directly after `.container`

```css
.container > .some-class:last-child {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="some-class">one</div>
    <div>
      <div class="some-class">sub-one</div>
      <div class="some-class">sub-two</div>
    </div>
  <div class="some-class">two</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a [child `>` combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator?retiredLocale=de):

```css
.container>.some-class:last-child {
  background: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="some-class">one</div>
  <div>
      <div class="some-class">sub-one</div>
      <div class="some-class">sub-two</div>
  </div>
  <div class="some-class">two</div>
</div>
```

Please note that there is no `last-of-class` selector in CSS. The selector in the snippet above does the following:

```
.container>.some-class:last-child
```

1. It selects **all** elements that are the last child of their parent.
2. Then it removes elements that don't have a CSS class `some-class`.
3. It then removes all elements that are not children of elements with a CSS class `container`.

Your CSS declarations are then applied to the elements remaining.